# Turn cells red if it is clashed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to prevent a room from being double booked using colour coding.

The column of room IDs contains duplicates and has no order. Orange cells along the row show what dates the room has been booked for as you can see in the screenshot below:

---

[image: Data Screenshot]

---

What I want is for a cell to turn red if there is another booking on the same day in that same room. For example, if Group A booked 14th to 16th October and then Group B booked 16th to 18th October I want 14th to 15th and 17th to 18th marked orange for being booked and the 16th marked red for being double booked.

I have tweaked some code I got from another post but it only seems to only check/reference the first duplicated room ID, this means it will mark double bookings red as long as there are only two bookings for that room and date, if there are more it won't count it as a double booking.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim dict As Object, dict2 As Object, v, c As Range, c2 As Range
    Dim FindFirstOrangeCell As Integer, FindEndOfOrangeCell As Integer
    Dim p As Long, l As Variant, AddOne As Integer, z As String

    For d = 0 To 10
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        Set dict2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        With Sheets("Schedule")
            Set rng = .Range("D2:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        End With

        For Each c In rng.Cells
            v = c.Value
            FindFirstOrangeCell = 1
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                Do Until c.Offset(, FindFirstOrangeCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Or c.Offset(, FindFirstOrangeCell).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
                    FindFirstOrangeCell = FindFirstOrangeCell + 1
                Loop

            End If
            Set c2 = c.Offset(0, FindFirstOrangeCell)
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                If c2.Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Or c2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                    FindEndOfOrangeCell = 1
                    Do Until c2.Offset(, FindEndOfOrangeCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                        FindEndOfOrangeCell = FindEndOfOrangeCell + 1
                    Loop

                    If dict.exists(v) Then
                        If dict2.exists(dict(v)) Then
                            If Not dict2(dict(v)) Is Nothing Then

                                 For p = 0 To FindEndOfOrangeCell - 1
                                    Cells(1, dict2(dict(v)).Column).Select
                                     If Cells(1, dict2(dict(v)).Column) = Cells(1, c2.Column + p) Then
                                         dict2(dict(v)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                                         Cells(c2.Row, c2.Column + p).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                                     End If

                                     If Cells(1, dict2(dict(v)).Column + p) = Cells(1, c2.Column + AddOne) Then
                                         Cells(dict2(dict(v)).Row, dict2(dict(v)).Column + p).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                                         Cells(c2.Row, c2.Column + AddOne).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                                         AddOne = AddOne + 1
                                     End If
                                 Next p
                                 p = 0
                                 AddOne = 0
                            End If
                        End If
                    Else
                        Set dict(v) = c2
                        Set dict2(dict(v)) = c2
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next d

End Sub
```

I am new to VBA so if you see any bad practices that slow down my code or make it look bad please let me know how I can improve.

I have also posted this question to another forum [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-vba-macros/1224959-prevent-cells-from-clashing-vba)

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/wzlxaslq7h42oc3/Tester.xlsm/file) is a sample file to help to with understanding the data.

Comment: *if there are any advise that could make my code look neater or run faster,* This is not the right place to ask this. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if this code works and has no actual issue (no errors), this question is better asked at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not sure what your question is? Is your code working and you just want advice on how to make it **"better"**? or is there an issue with your code other then performance issue?

Comment: My code does not work the way I want it to, as the program is only taking the first reference to check for all the dates, for example, if room ID 511 on third row is occupied during 17oct to 19oct and there is 2 other data with room ID 511 occupied on 14oct to 16oct, the 2 other data will not turned red, as they are checking the cells on 17oct to 19 oct. Getting advise is not my main problem here, rather an additional help to my code instead. so sorry if I am unclear with the questions and my description.

Comment: The link to the sample file is invalid, do you have another one?

Comment: Hi, are you able to access this then? http://www.mediafire.com/file/wzlxaslq7h42oc3/Tester.xlsm/file

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the copy. I'll take a look when I get a moment

Comment: Alright, Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Just somethingI want to check, is every booking 3 days long and if two a day is double booked do you want all three days to go red or only the day that is double booked?

Comment: The booking is not always 3 days long and i want the double booked day to turn red only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find the issue in your code but I ended up eventually just rewriting it all as you can see below.

I do know that one of the issues was from where you tried to get a range of all the room numbers. You used the first column which ends in a merged cell and when VBA runs into these it takes the top left cell reference and this was cutting off the last two rows of your sheet in the checks.

```
Public Sub Tester()

    Dim roomRange As Range
    Dim roomCell As Range
    Dim roomNum As Long
    Dim bookingStart As Long
    Dim bookingEnd As Long
    Dim bookingRange As Range
    Dim bookingCell As Range
    Dim bookingDict As Object
    Set bookingDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim cellColour As Long

    With Sheets("Schedule") 'Get all room numbers
        Set roomRange = .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    For Each roomCell In roomRange.Cells
        roomNum = roomCell.Value
        If Len(roomNum) > 0 Then

            'Find where booking starts
            bookingStart = 1
            cellColour = roomCell.Offset(0, bookingStart).Interior.ColorIndex
            Do Until cellColour = 44 Or cellColour = xlColorIndexNone Or cellColour = 3
                bookingStart = bookingStart + 1
                cellColour = roomCell.Offset(0, bookingStart).Interior.ColorIndex
            Loop

            'If there was a booking start
            If cellColour <> xlColorIndexNone Then
                'Find where booking ends
                bookingEnd = bookingStart
                cellColour = roomCell.Offset(0, bookingEnd + 1).Interior.ColorIndex
                Do Until cellColour <> 44 And cellColour <> 3
                    bookingEnd = bookingEnd + 1
                    cellColour = roomCell.Offset(0, bookingEnd + 1).Interior.ColorIndex
                Loop

                'Get booking cells
                Set bookingRange = Range(Cells(roomCell.Row, bookingStart + 3), Cells(roomCell.Row, bookingEnd + 3))
                For Each bookingCell In bookingRange.Cells

                    'If room already booked
                    If bookingDict.exists(roomNum & bookingCell.Column) Then
                        bookingCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                        bookingDict(roomNum & bookingCell.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Else 'If this is the first booking
                        bookingDict.Add roomNum & bookingCell.Column, bookingCell
                    End If

                Next bookingCell
            End If
        End If
    Next roomCell
End Sub
```

If you have any further issues with it just leave me a comment and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping and you even comment what each code does to help me understand each part.